# Why I get a blank screen or a screen freeze randomly? (Radeon Graphics issue?)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, display, amd-graphics

My Ubuntu 16.04.2 system almost never boots without "radeon.modeset=0" flag in CMDLINE. Even if it manages to boot normally with fully working graphics, then it randomly freezes at some screen (nothing works!). Now I'm typing from the same system and I am scared to turn off this system because I don't know if it will boot normally ever. 
I have tried so many things to fix this problem like removing fglrx-* packages, reinstalling xorg-server completely, installing proprietary drivers from AMD (which was unsuccessful) but the problem still persists.
Here is some DMESG log from the current boot:

```
dmesg | grep radeon


[   20.338211] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   20.811775] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[   20.812316] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[   20.812319] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[   20.812421] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   20.812423] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   21.299901] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   21.467270] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[   21.467274] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c00
[   21.468017] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001435a18
[   21.488049] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c18
[   21.488054] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c1c
[   21.488057] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c04
[   21.488059] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c08
[   21.488062] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c0c
[   21.488064] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c10
[   21.488071] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   21.488108] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   21.488137] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   23.230164] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[   23.652404] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   23.652642] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   23.718196] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
[   23.718324] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   23.809280] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[   23.809288] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF
[   23.809321] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[   23.809324] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   24.631934] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   24.703143] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   24.703147] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[   24.703150] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[   24.704678] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[   24.704685] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   24.704733] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   24.704857] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   25.635447] [drm:radeon_acpi_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller
[   25.635640] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   33.270152] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   33.270157] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[   33.270160] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[   33.271687] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[   54.562435] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   54.562439] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[   54.562442] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[   54.563971] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[ 2456.807100] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[ 2456.807105] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[ 2456.807108] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[ 2456.808649] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[ 2457.995824] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2459.015301] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2460.034789] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2461.054276] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2462.073763] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2463.093252] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2464.111716] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2465.131204] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2466.150691] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2467.170179] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2467.190169] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, giving up!!!
[ 2467.190223] [drm:evergreen_startup.part.13 [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: error initializing UVD (-1).
[ 2469.072416] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[ 2469.072419] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c00
[ 2469.073152] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001435a18
[ 2469.093200] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c18
[ 2469.093202] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c1c
[ 2469.093203] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c04
[ 2469.093205] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c08
[ 2469.093207] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c0c
[ 2469.093208] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c10
[ 2471.236519] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[ 2471.236522] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[ 2471.236524] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[ 2471.238066] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[ 2472.428332] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2473.444731] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2474.463881] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2475.480701] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2476.499584] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2477.516671] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2478.534445] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2479.551648] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2480.569168] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2481.586626] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[ 2481.606616] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, giving up!!!
[ 2481.606648] [drm:evergreen_startup.part.13 [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: error initializing UVD (-1).
[ 2563.237858] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[ 2563.237862] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[ 2563.237865] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[ 2563.239393] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
[ 2565.960240] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[ 2565.960243] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c00
[ 2565.960976] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001435a18
[ 2565.981017] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c18
[ 2565.981019] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c1c
[ 2565.981021] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c04
[ 2565.981022] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c08
[ 2565.981024] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c0c
[ 2565.981025] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800adb27c10
[ 2568.128559] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[ 2568.128562] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc00
[ 2568.128564] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a799cc0c
[ 2568.130118] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001c32118
```

And some information about display drivers:

```
lspci -k | grep -A3 VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7420G]
    DeviceName: AMD TRINITY SCRAPPER MOBILE LITE Graphics
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Trinity [Radeon HD 7420G]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
    DeviceName: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions/suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: The first suggestion to the black screen thing is to hit ctrl + alt + f1 and login with your credentials (user name and password) then hit the command `sudo startx .

Comment: Ofcourse I've tried that. It won't work since the system  gets freezed in a black screen. The only thing I can do when there's blank screen or random screen is force shutdown using power button.  NOTE: I can still login to Ubuntu by using nomodeset in CMDLINE. (But I can't stay in that mode for long cuz my pc will overheat and eventually shutdown automatically)

Comment: Before going into the details, check the checksum of the downloaded iso and compare it to the one on the site, chances are this is what's causing the black screen and freezes (I had a similar problem).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using the same system from past 4 months and I haven't faced this issue until this week. All this happened after I installed some regional fonts and logged out without closing running applications. (I've removed those font packages now). 
I used to face a similar problem with Linux Mint 17 and that's the reason I've switched to Ubuntu 4 months back.
So I suspect it must be something related to the graphics drivers.